# Calling .NET DLL in Delphi causes access violation

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have created a dll  with .net as you can see :

```
namespace SymfaEncryption
{
    public class SyEnc
    {
        //-----

        public string test(string a)
        {
            return a;
        }
}
}
```

I have added the dll using `import component and register with regasm`. I call my dll function as you can see :

```
procedure TfrmMain.btn676767Click(Sender: TObject);
var
SyEncobject :SyEnc;
bresult : string;
begin

             bresult:=  SyEncobject.test('a');
            ShowMessage(bresult);

end;

end.
```

When I click on the button I get this error :

[image]

Here is my dll tlb

```
unit SymfaEncryption_TLB;

// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING                                                                    
// -------                                                                    
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from a       
// Type Library. If this type library is explicitly or indirectly (via        
// another type library referring to this type library) re-imported, or the   
// 'Refresh' command of the Type Library Editor activated while editing the   
// Type Library, the contents of this file will be regenerated and all        
// manual modifications will be lost.                                         
// ************************************************************************ //

// $Rev: 17244 $
// File generated on 2/27/2021 2:42:42 PM from Type Library described below.

// ************************************************************************  //
// Type Lib: E:\Project\NewSymfaEncryption\SymfaEncryption\SymfaEncryption\bin\Debug\SymfaEncryption.tlb (1)
// LIBID: {5BFA4580-74FF-412D-A11C-AACADE7EBA7A}
// LCID: 0
// Helpfile: 
// HelpString: Symfa Encryptor And Decryptor
// DepndLst: 
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb)
//   (2) v2.4 mscorlib, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb)
// Errors:
//   Error creating palette bitmap of (TSyEnc) : Server mscoree.dll contains no icons
// ************************************************************************ //
// *************************************************************************//
// NOTE:                                                                      
// Items guarded by $IFDEF_LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME are used by properties  
// which return objects that may need to be explicitly created via a function 
// call prior to any access via the property. These items have been disabled  
// in order to prevent accidental use from within the object inspector. You   
// may enable them by defining LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME or by selectively   
// removing them from the $IFDEF blocks. However, such items must still be    
// programmatically created via a method of the appropriate CoClass before    
// they can be used.                                                          
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} // Unit must be compiled without type-checked pointers. 
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
{$ALIGN 4}
interface

uses Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Graphics, mscorlib_TLB, OleServer, StdVCL, Variants;
  


// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:        
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx                                      
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx                                      
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx                                       
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx                                        
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  SymfaEncryptionMajorVersion = 1;
  SymfaEncryptionMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_SymfaEncryption: TGUID = '{5BFA4580-74FF-412D-A11C-AACADE7EBA7A}';

  IID__SyEnc: TGUID = '{02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}';
  CLASS_SyEnc: TGUID = '{B78BCEEC-5AD0-3C21-AE13-82FF22A4DD78}';
type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary                    
// *********************************************************************//
  _SyEnc = interface;
  _SyEncDisp = dispinterface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library                       
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)              
// *********************************************************************//
  SyEnc = _SyEnc;


// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: _SyEnc
// Flags:     (4560) Hidden Dual NonExtensible OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}
// *********************************************************************//
  _SyEnc = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}']
    function Get_ToString: WideString; safecall;
    function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool; safecall;
    function GetHashCode: Integer; safecall;
    function GetType: _Type; safecall;
    function test(const a: WideString): WideString; safecall;
    function DecryptFileToText(const SourceFilePath: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString): WideString; safecall;
    procedure EncryptTextToFile(const Data: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString; 
                                const DestinationFile: WideString); safecall;
    property ToString: WideString read Get_ToString;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  _SyEncDisp
// Flags:     (4560) Hidden Dual NonExtensible OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}
// *********************************************************************//
  _SyEncDisp = dispinterface
    ['{02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}']
    property ToString: WideString readonly dispid 0;
    function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool; dispid 1610743809;
    function GetHashCode: Integer; dispid 1610743810;
    function GetType: _Type; dispid 1610743811;
    function test(const a: WideString): WideString; dispid 1610743812;
    function DecryptFileToText(const SourceFilePath: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString): WideString; dispid 1610743813;
    procedure EncryptTextToFile(const Data: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString; 
                                const DestinationFile: WideString); dispid 1610743814;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoSyEnc provides a Create and CreateRemote method to          
// create instances of the default interface _SyEnc exposed by              
// the CoClass SyEnc. The functions are intended to be used by             
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the         
// server of this typelibrary.                                            
// *********************************************************************//
  CoSyEnc = class
    class function Create: _SyEnc;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _SyEnc;
  end;


// *********************************************************************//
// OLE Server Proxy class declaration
// Server Object    : TSyEnc
// Help String      : 
// Default Interface: _SyEnc
// Def. Intf. DISP? : No
// Event   Interface: 
// TypeFlags        : (2) CanCreate
// *********************************************************************//
{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
  TSyEncProperties= class;
{$ENDIF}
  TSyEnc = class(TOleServer)
  private
    FIntf: _SyEnc;
{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
    FProps: TSyEncProperties;
    function GetServerProperties: TSyEncProperties;
{$ENDIF}
    function GetDefaultInterface: _SyEnc;
  protected
    procedure InitServerData; override;
    function Get_ToString: WideString;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Connect; override;
    procedure ConnectTo(svrIntf: _SyEnc);
    procedure Disconnect; override;
    function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool;
    function GetHashCode: Integer;
    function GetType: _Type;
    function test(const a: WideString): WideString;
    function DecryptFileToText(const SourceFilePath: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString): WideString;
    procedure EncryptTextToFile(const Data: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString; 
                                const DestinationFile: WideString);
    property DefaultInterface: _SyEnc read GetDefaultInterface;
    property ToString: WideString read Get_ToString;
  published
{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
    property Server: TSyEncProperties read GetServerProperties;
{$ENDIF}
  end;

{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
// *********************************************************************//
// OLE Server Properties Proxy Class
// Server Object    : TSyEnc
// (This object is used by the IDE's Property Inspector to allow editing
//  of the properties of this server)
// *********************************************************************//
 TSyEncProperties = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FServer:    TSyEnc;
    function    GetDefaultInterface: _SyEnc;
    constructor Create(AServer: TSyEnc);
  protected
    function Get_ToString: WideString;
  public
    property DefaultInterface: _SyEnc read GetDefaultInterface;
  published
  end;
{$ENDIF}


procedure Register;

resourcestring
  dtlServerPage = 'ActiveX';

  dtlOcxPage = 'ActiveX';

implementation

uses ComObj;

class function CoSyEnc.Create: _SyEnc;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_SyEnc) as _SyEnc;
end;

class function CoSyEnc.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _SyEnc;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_SyEnc) as _SyEnc;
end;

procedure TSyEnc.InitServerData;
const
  CServerData: TServerData = (
    ClassID:   '{B78BCEEC-5AD0-3C21-AE13-82FF22A4DD78}';
    IntfIID:   '{02884537-CA4F-3A76-B957-8CE1813FC851}';
    EventIID:  '';
    LicenseKey: nil;
    Version: 500);
begin
  ServerData := @CServerData;
end;

procedure TSyEnc.Connect;
var
  punk: IUnknown;
begin
  if FIntf = nil then
  begin
    punk := GetServer;
    Fintf:= punk as _SyEnc;
  end;
end;

procedure TSyEnc.ConnectTo(svrIntf: _SyEnc);
begin
  Disconnect;
  FIntf := svrIntf;
end;

procedure TSyEnc.DisConnect;
begin
  if Fintf <> nil then
  begin
    FIntf := nil;
  end;
end;

function TSyEnc.GetDefaultInterface: _SyEnc;
begin
  if FIntf = nil then
    Connect;
  Assert(FIntf <> nil, 'DefaultInterface is NULL. Component is not connected to Server. You must call "Connect" or "ConnectTo" before this operation');
  Result := FIntf;
end;

constructor TSyEnc.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
  FProps := TSyEncProperties.Create(Self);
{$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TSyEnc.Destroy;
begin
{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
  FProps.Free;
{$ENDIF}
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
function TSyEnc.GetServerProperties: TSyEncProperties;
begin
  Result := FProps;
end;
{$ENDIF}

function TSyEnc.Get_ToString: WideString;
begin
    Result := DefaultInterface.ToString;
end;

function TSyEnc.Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.Equals(obj);
end;

function TSyEnc.GetHashCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.GetHashCode;
end;

function TSyEnc.GetType: _Type;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.GetType;
end;

function TSyEnc.test(const a: WideString): WideString;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.test(a);
end;

function TSyEnc.DecryptFileToText(const SourceFilePath: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString): WideString;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.DecryptFileToText(SourceFilePath, ReceptionID);
end;

procedure TSyEnc.EncryptTextToFile(const Data: WideString; const ReceptionID: WideString; 
                                   const DestinationFile: WideString);
begin
  DefaultInterface.EncryptTextToFile(Data, ReceptionID, DestinationFile);
end;

{$IFDEF LIVE_SERVER_AT_DESIGN_TIME}
constructor TSyEncProperties.Create(AServer: TSyEnc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FServer := AServer;
end;

function TSyEncProperties.GetDefaultInterface: _SyEnc;
begin
  Result := FServer.DefaultInterface;
end;

function TSyEncProperties.Get_ToString: WideString;
begin
    Result := DefaultInterface.ToString;
end;

{$ENDIF}

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents(dtlServerPage, [TSyEnc]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Where is the `SyEncobject` object created?

Comment: As a sidenote, there are cryptographic libraries available for Delphi.

Comment: You don't create the object so not surprisingly you see this error.

Comment: I add the dll with import library type

Comment: You need to create the COM object and assign it to `SyEncobject`. Calling a method through a `nil` reference can't work.

Comment: I added this part to my code : SyEncobject  :=SyEnc.Create(Self); but i get this error :synenc does not contain a member with name create

Comment: If you look at the generated code, you will see you need to use `SyEncobject := CoSyEnc.Create;`.

Comment: Definitely valuable to read the import library